# Excel: SafeAs .txt with VBA: Decimal seperator is changed

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem when saving a worksheet with VBA in Excel.

I have to Cope a Worksheet into a new workbook and safe that as an .xls with the format actually beeing 42 (so Text).

I have already red, that I should set the decimal seperator manually to "," , safe with local=True and do not safe before closing.

The Problem is, that the Document then has no Decimals at all.

My thougth was, that the local config for decimals is 0 decimals. Is that a thing, or am I missing something?

My Code:

```
Function SafeWorksheetToDesktopAs(Filename, Worksheet As String, Fileformat As Integer)

Dim SavePath    As String
Dim MLC_Project As String
Dim strPath     As String
Dim lCtr        As Long
Dim Datum       As String

Datum = Format(Now(), "yyyymmdd")
MLC_Project = Worksheets("Deckblatt").Range("E2")
strPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" & MLC_Project & "\" & Datum
SavePath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & "\" & MLC_Project & "\" & Datum & "\" & Filename

arrpath = Split(strPath, "\")
strPath = arrpath(LBound(arrpath)) & "\"

For lCtr = LBound(arrpath) + 1 To UBound(arrpath)
    strPath = strPath & arrpath(lCtr) & "\"
    If Dir(strPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then
       MkDir strPath
    End If
Next

    Sheets(Worksheet).Select
    Sheets(Worksheet).Copy
    ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.DecimalSeparator = ","
    Application.ThousandsSeparator = "."
    Application.UseSystemSeparators = False
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=SavePath, Fileformat:=Fileformat, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False

End Function
```

Comment: Never Mind... It does work like that, it just won't show decimals if there aren't any, which is strange but ok...

Comment: Most likely, the format of the cell is `General`.  If you want to always see a decimal, format the cell as `Number` with the desired number of trailing zero's.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But it is fine for me, as it does not have to look pretty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never Mind... It does work like that, it just won't show decimals if there aren't any, which is strange but ok...